# Preventing assignment from unique_ptr to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I want to prevent code like this:

```
unique_ptr<ClassA> captr = unique_ptr<ClassA>(new ClassA());
....
shared_ptr<Base> sptr = move(captr);
```

This code should generate compiler error, but instead it compiles and generates double frees and other weird errors at runtime. Assigning a unique_ptr to shared_ptr makes no sense at all. If something is declared unique_ptr it is not meant to be shared. But if assignment of unique_ptr to shared_ptr is allowed then this restriction is gone.

And unfortunately is a mistake that is far too easily made when some functions return unique_ptr and some take shared_ptr as arguments.

Question is: how do I disallow these assignments for ALL templated variations of unique_ptr and shared_ptr, regardless of the specific class that they are templated as?

I'm thinking of something like declaring an assignment operator as deleted, but I'm not sure what such a declaration would look like.

Comment: -1 "Assigning a unique_ptr to shared_ptr makes no sense at all." is incorrect. The problem is with your class `A`. You forgot to show that.

Comment: It doesn't because if I declare something as "unique" then someone can't just make it shared. It makes no sense. A unique pointer should be unique ie ONE instance globally at any time and only in one place.

Comment: @user1953157: They aren't able to "just make it shared", they have to have ownership and then explicitly type out `move`. If you don't want to lose ownership of something, don't move it! Consider that special work had to be done to allow this (`shared_ptr` has a constructor for this), you think this is a mistake?

Comment: As the other comments say, there's nothing wrong with the code or the concept of changing from unique to shared ownership. The object starts off with one owner then later it gets multiple owners, that's not a problem and isn't causing your memory corruption (you're probably causing that yourself.) You can't declare an assignment operator as a non-member, so you'd need to edit the `shared_ptr` code, which should be a big clue what you're doing is completely wrong-headed and you should stop trying.

Comment: @GManNickG return values are rvalues.  This code is legit:
unique_ptr<A> foo() { return unique_ptr<A>(new A()); } bar() { shared_ptr<A> b = foo(); }  Nevertheless, this code does not cause the A to be destroyed twice.  The shared_ptr's constructor carefully defuses the unique_ptr.

Comment: @dspeyer: Yeah, was going off OP's example. But in all cases it's always up to the user of the value.

Answer (score 9):

```
unique_ptr<ClassA> captr = unique_ptr<ClassA>(new ClassA());
....
shared_ptr<Base> sptr = move(captr);
```

This is indeed correct code. What is happening here is:

1. a resource is captured via `unique_ptr` in `captr`.
2. The resource is later moved to  `shared_ptr sptr` making your `captr` empty.
3. The resource is now owned by `sptr`.
4. The destructor of `unique_ptr` won't destroy that resource, because it's not owning it anymore.

Maybe this is simplified code and you are using a custom deleter for `unique_ptr<ClassA>` and not using that deleter in `shared_ptr`'s constructor?
Or, maybe your `Base` class and `Derived` class have a resource handling bug internally?
Another option could be you do something wrong in between those two pieces of code.